# patsubst in GNU make returns nothing

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to have my cpp source files and my object files in separate directories, so I'm trying to use Make's patsubst to replace the paths. After nothing was compiling, I made a phony target to simply print out the relevant variables and I discovered that patsubst was returning nothing. This doesn't make a lot of sense to me, as from what I can tell, targets that don't match the pattern should pass through unchanged, so even if my patterns are malformed I should still be seeing *something* get returned.

My variables are declared like this:

```
SRC_DIR := source/
SRC := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)*.cpp)

OBJ_DIR := obj/
OBJ := $(PATSUBST $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)%.o, $(SRC))
```

My phony target that just prints out the above variables looks like this:

```
.PHONY: print
print:
    @echo $(SRC_DIR)
    @echo $(SRC)
    @echo $(OBJ_DIR)
    @echo $(OBJ)
```

and the result of running `make print` is this:

```
user@athena:~/proj$ make print
source/
source/main.cpp source/util.cpp
obj/

user@athena:~/proj$
```

#### Other things I've tried

I've tried SRC_DIR and OBJ_DIR having trailing slashes and not having them, I've tried `$(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)%.o)` which *did* work, and $(OBJ) would have both main.o and util.o, but then my static rule (`$(OBJ): $(OBJ_DIR)%.o : $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp`) would only trigger for main.cpp, and wouldn't try to compile util.cpp, which I'm considering a completely separate issue?

I hope I'm just doing something dumb and there's a simple fix, but I've been racking my brain and I can't see what would be causing patsubst to just be blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like (virtually) all programming languages, makefiles are case-sensitive.  `$(FOO)` is not the same as `$(foo)`, and `$(PATSUBST ...)` is not the same as `$(patsubst ...)`.

In fact, `$(PATSUBST ...)` is nothing and expands to the empty string.

Comment: God okay, don’t know why I was typing it in caps and just didn’t even notice, thanks 